# Append value into [[String: String]]()

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to add value into `[[String: String]]()` as follow:

```
let realm = try! Realm()
let nrcObj = realm.objects(ObjectNRC.self)
for nrc in nrcObj {
    nrcTownshipCode["value"] = nrc.regionCode
    nrcTownshipCode["display"] = nrc.regionCode
}
```

But when I did like that, I've encountered following error message.

> Cannot subscript a value of type '[[String : String]]' with an index
>   of type 'String'

Please suggest me how to do it. Thanks.

Comment: Your nrc object is may be array type not dictionary. Show more code related to nrcObj type.

Comment: @PaulMarshal I've added some codes. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to do is to treat `[[String: String]]` as dictionary which is *not*! Actually, `[[String: String]]` is an array of dictionaries (`[String: String]`). So what would you need to do instead -for instance-:

```
 for nrc in nrcObj {
     nrcTownshipCode[0]["value"] = nrc.regionCode
     nrcTownshipCode[0]["display"] = nrc.regionCode
 }
```

means that you would iterate through `nrcObj` and append values for the *first* dictionary in your array. Note that it might not be your desired result, but it describes your issue and how you could fix it. For instance, you might want to add an additional variable to hold the iteration count and use it as an index for your array:

```
var i = 0
for nrc in nrcObj {
     nrcTownshipCode[i]["value"] = nrc.regionCode
     nrcTownshipCode[i]["display"] = nrc.regionCode

     i += 1
 }
```